# Check details of uninstalled packages

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, package-management, 15.04, 16.04

How to check details of yet-to-be installed packages? That is I want to figureout what binaries a package will install before installing it.

E.g.

> dpkg -l binutils*

Above lists out packages of mentioned pattern and says binutils is installed but binutils-gold is not.

> dpkg -L binutils

Above lists out all binaries or atleast all files binutils installs in your system. I want to query similarly binutils-gold before installing it and same for any other package.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `--dry-run` option of `apt` and/or `apt-get` to see all effect of a single `apt` / `apt-get` command

Quoting the `apt-get` man page

> -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
>
> ```
>        No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on the current system state but do not
>        actually change the system. Locking will be disabled (Debug::NoLocking) so the system state could change
>        while apt-get is running. Simulations can also be executed by non-root users which might not have read
>        access to all apt configuration distorting the simulation. A notice expressing this warning is also
>        shown by default for non-root users (APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note). Configuration Item:
>        APT::Get::Simulate.
> ```

Comment: In addition to @dufte answer you as well can use `apt-cache show <package-name> to list all dependencies and info contained in the `control` file inside the `.deb` archive.